# Shell_exec giving different outputs with identical input

Tags: php, linux, bash

I'm trying to return the content of a folder in a Linux enviroment.
To do this I run the code below:

```
//this line returns folders and files from current folder
$reg = shell_exec ("ls -A");
//in this line I just try to show the info with the desired structure.
$reg = "stat --printf='%n|%s|%s|%F|%y|%a' ".$reg." | numfmt --to=iec-i --field=2 --delimiter='|' --suffix=B";
//This prints the content of $reg
echo $reg;
//I manually input the string returned by $reg and I receive the correct output
echo shell_exec ("stat --printf='%n|%s|%s|%F|%y|%a' .file1 file2 | numfmt --to=iec-i --field=2 --delimiter='|' --suffix=B");
//This just prints the result of "stat --printf='%n|%s|%s|%F|%y|%a' .file1"
echo shell_exec ($reg);
```

The problem is that the two last "echo" instructions return different outputs given (in theory) identical inputs.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `ls` detects that it's being piped into another command it writes one file per line, screwing up your command.

You could either replace them with spaces

```
$reg= str_replace("\n", " ", shell_exec("ls -A"));
```

or use `ls` as a substitution

```
$reg = "stat --printf='%n|%s|%s|%F|%y|%a' $(ls -A) | numfmt --to=iec-i --field=2 --delimiter='|' --suffix=B";
```